# how to exclude app.config from setup deployment project

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, windows-installer, settings

How to exclude app.config from setup deployment project?

I must maintain encrypted sections in app.config and the only (semi) embeded way I know is by running code with RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider or DPAPI provider.  Since I have to run that code the question arises: when to run it.  Since there seem to be some problems using Rsa under windows 7 (some end user's will NOT have admin rights on it) I concentrated on DPAPI which is machine dependent.  Therefore I can not encrypt app.config on my developer machine.  So I have to do it on a target machine.
If application does not find any config files, then it creates one.  And that's what I am trying to do: to exclude app.config from msi setup project, so that whe app is run for the first time, settings are created from defaults and my encryption code runs on it.
Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Anybody else?  I found an exlude filter though for my exe file and I put there *.config.  Now I'll test it and get back to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Setup Deployment project you could for the Primary Output folder enter in the Exclude property: app.config

Comment: I don't see app.config as listed in my Project Output file list.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, could you change the app.config -> properties -> Build Action from "Content" to "None"?