# Exclude an app.config file from Build

Tags: c#

I am currently having an issue with removing the app.config file from my project.
I wish to have a single .exe file, however, every time I delete the app.config the program will not run.

Does anyone know of a solution to prevent the application from trying to find a app.config file?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource` then build it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to exclude app.config from setup deployment project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794399/how-to-exclude-app-config-from-setup-deployment-project)

Comment: Will not run? What are the contents of ˋapp.config` when it runs?

Comment: Are you getting any exception when running without the app.config file ? You would have seen that the Visual Studio build would create a .exe.config with the contents of your app.config file. It is likely that your application is trying to read the config file and it its absence throwing an exception and failing. Looking at your exception stacktrace, will give you the details of the code which is reading the config file.

Comment: Funnily enough, to solve the problem I had to set the 'app.config' file to output the 'app.config' as an additional file... This stopped it from being created, whereas having it set to 'never copy to output directory'  still copied it over.